# Intellij IDEA: looking for plugin to generate nice comment headers

Tags: intellij-idea, development-environment

I found very useful dividing unit-test suite into logical blocks (for each method) with comment block:

```
***************************************
***********                 ***********
***********  getTotalValue  ***********
***********                 ***********
***************************************
```

Generating it manually requires lots of effort. Is there a plugin for IDEA which could do it automatically?

Comment: Depending on how attached you are to the exact formatting of the comment, you could create a custom Live Template (`Preferences > Live Templeates`).

Comment: ...what?  What are you looking for?

Comment: @Makoto Looking for a way to generate such a formatted frame automatically.

Comment: Search help for _Live Templates_ (that @kuporific mentioned). Or you can view online at http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/live-templates.html

Answer (score 2):

*p.s i don't know how Live templates works, maybe they are better, but it's a way to do it (or at least, how i generally do this)*

You *could* edit the File template for JUnit 4 (or what you use, override the `Test method` template)

So do Right click in a `source file > New file > Edit File templates...`

And go to `Code` tab and select what you want to edit

[image]

and edit the template with

```
***************************************
***********                 ***********
***********  ${NAME}        ***********
***********                 ***********
***************************************
```

example:

[image]

and you could get the effect you want. (p.s maybe the spaces will looks bad, but try)

With this, when you add new tests (with for example, generate missing tests) it will add it for you.

Usually i use this to add the JavaDoc `@author` and `@since` everytime i create a class